# Having a global variable for my game screens

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

From **Main.as** I determine device screen size. I then take that info to the Screen class like so:

```
new Screen(_width, _height);
```

Now I'm trying to pass the _width, _height to the **Menu**, **Game**, classes that I have extending **Screen**

Is this how I should go about this?

Comment: Assuming `Screen` exposes the values you pass to the constructor, should they not be available within `Menu` and `Game` as properties they own if they extend it?

Comment: I just wanted `Screen` to hold the values for `Menu` and `Game` so they know the width of the application. Should I be doing this a completely different way?

Comment: Are any of those three classes your document class? The document class is the best place to define the screen sizes and potentially store them in static properties so you can refer to them elsewhere easily.

Comment: Yes, my document class is the main class. From the main class  addChild the `Screen`, which delegates adding other screens like `Menu` and `Game`. `Menu` and `Game` extend the `Screen` class. I just don't know how to hold vars that can be access from anywhere, especially the WIDTH and HEIGHT of the application

Comment: I'll add an answer to cover that, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your document class `Main`, you could more easily achieve what you want like this:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{

    private static var _width:int;
    private static var _height:int;


    public function Main()
    {
        _width = stage.stageWidth;
        _height = stage.stageHeight;
    }


    public static function get width():int{ return _width; }
    public static function get height():int{ return _height; }

}
```

Used like:

```
trace( Main.width, Main.height );
```

---

inb4 static is bad: This is an immutable value that is useful in many areas of a game / application. In my opinion it is a perfect example of where static should be used.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but is this best practices?

Comment: @Tom I'm confident that this is a good approach for this particular scenario. You should be cautious of using the same approach for less generic, multi-purpose data though.

Comment: Would I want to temporarily store a highscore the same way?

Comment: @Tom Because a highscore is case-specific, I would suggested passing it through from wherever it is generated to wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

try to add static vars in your Main class:

```
public static var appWidth   :int;
public static var appHeight  :int;
```

after you define them, you can access them anywhere on your code like this:

```
var myHeight:int = Main.appHeight;
```

Hope this could help you.

if you want to add it to Screen and not on Main you can do the same and access values like this:

```
var myWidth  :int  = Screen.appWidth;
var myHeight :int  = Screen.appHeight;
```